# How reload main window?

Tags: c#, winforms

I need close current main window and show new main window.
First load Main.

```
static class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        var main = new Main();
        Application.Run(main);
    }
}
```

In event main I need close and show new clear Main.
I tried so:

```
private void ChangeUsers()
{
    this.Visible = false;
    var window = new Main();
    window.Show();
    this.Close();
}
```

but this not correct work.

Comment: why do you need to close the window, and then show it again? What does this achieve for you?

Comment: I make Fast User Switching. In the MAIN window is a function which is run by intsilizatsii MAIN. I will not have to refresh the data, but simply started with a chitym class.

Comment: Please provide more details as to why the need to close and reopen the main window.

Comment: And what is not working correctly? Window is not shown? Application stops?

Comment: Have you tried re-initializing the main windows by: 1) Disposing and clearing the controls, 2) Reinitializing all class fields and properties, and 3) Calling the InitializeControls() method?

Comment: I do not want to do it, too much action and will do what I can miss something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This shows the form modally and lets the form return a DialogResult to indicate whether to re-show the form.

```
static class Program
{
  [STAThread]
  static void Main()
  {
      Main main;
      do
      {
         main = new Main();
      } while (DialogResult.OK == main.ShowDialog ());
  }
} 

private void ChangeUsers()
{
    this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
    this.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Change main method to this:

```
static class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        new Main().Show();
        Application.Run();
    }
}
```

And note that you should call `Application.Exit()` to close application.

Answer (score 1):

You can maybe do something like this:

```
static class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        var loader = new Loader();
        Application.Run(loader);
    }
}

public class Loader : Form 
{
    public Loader()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Main win = new Main();
        win.Show();
        this.Hide();
    }

}

public class Main : Form 
{

}
```

This way, the Loader form (which is the running form will not be closed, but hidden). And you can create as many Main forms (windows) as you want. When you want to close the application, send a message to the Loader form to quit.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that, since closing the main window will send a message to the carrier process to be ended, and then your program no longer has control (can't execute any more code).

provide something like logging off instead, close DB connections, close all child windows, return to the login screen again to achieve "Fast User Switching" feature.

**P.S:** This method has the best effect if the main window were an MDI window.